# prove that a piecewise function at an isolated point is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

[image]

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x = 3$

My proof

We perform a few small calculations to determine that the function is:
$$
f(x):=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
     -x+2 & \text{ if } x\leq 2\\
      2 & \text{ if } x=3\\
      1 & \text{ if } x \geq 4
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The domain of the function is $(-\infty, 2] \cup \{ 3 \} \cup [4, \infty)$. \

Before demonstrating, let's recall the definition of continuity:

$(X, d_x),(Y, d_y),$ Metric spaces, $f: E\subseteq X \to Y$, $x_0 \in D(f)$. We say that $f$ is continuous at $x=x_0$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0,$ such that: if $x \in D(f)$ and $d_x( x, x_0) < \delta,$ then $d_y(f(x), f(x_0)) < \epsilon$.

and the definition of isolated point:

Given a set $A$ and a point $x \in A$, $x$ is an isolated point of $A$ if and only if $x \in A $ and $ \exists r >0$ such that $B_r( x) \cap A=\{ x \}$
\

Continuing with the demonstration, we note that the point $x=3$ is an isolated point, for this reason we cannot approach it from the right or from the left. Then let $x_0 \in D(f)$, more specifically $x_0 = 3$. Let $\delta > 0$ and $x \in D(f)$ satisfy $d(x, x_0) < \delta$. By definition of distance we have $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$ and since $x_0$ is an isolated point we can write it:
$$
     (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta) \cap D(f) =\{ x_0 \}
$$
Now let's choose any $\epsilon>0$. Then we have that for any $x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta) \cap D(f) =\{ x_0 \}$ :
$$
|f(x)-f(x_0)|=|f(x_0)-f(x_0)|= |2-2|= 0 < \epsilon .
$$
This satisfies the continuity condition at $x_0$, and the limit in this case is trivially equal to $f(x)$.

is this test correct?

Comment: Weird exercise you were given there, but your proof is correct.

Comment: Probably an exercise to show that odd things can be true when the domain is disconnected. What would have been a jump discontinuity isn't so because the domain itself is disconnected.

Comment: @0XLR Thanks for your answer, yes I think he put it for that, yes it's weird like all the homework my profesor gives me

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you for your answer, I really need to get a good grade on this assignment

Comment: If the domain of a function is discrete, the function is always continuous. That means, for example, any sequence is continuous. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297344/are-sequences-continuous#:~:text=Any%20sequence%20Z%2B%E2%86%92Y,at%20a%22%20may%20seem%20nonsensical.).

Comment: @durianice thanks for your contribution